# How to create a text field

Tags: objective-c

I'm new to cocoa. I create project where I have one textField and one button. I make function for button, where I start my other function and it's ok. But I need to take number value from textField as parameter for my function...like this:

```
@implementation AppController

- (IBAction)StartReconstruction:(id)sender {
int RecLine = //here i need something like textField1.GetIntValue();
drawGL(RecLine);
}
@end
```

In IB I only create number formated text field. But I don't know how to call it from code :(

thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the value from the `UITextField` is a string you will need to use the `NSNumberFomatter`

```
NSNumberFormatter * formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber someNumber = [formatter numberFromString:myTextField.text];
int RecLine = [someNumber intValue];
```

Here is a [list of the NSNumberFormatterStyles](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)